# Printing Time to Serial Port

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, time

I am reading sensory data that comes from the digital inputs(two DHT11 Humidity sensors using adafruit library.) and I would like to add a hh:mm:ss real time counts next to them. I try to use the time.h library but could not understand how to worked it in that way.

My code is;

```
#include "DHT.h"

#define DHT1PIN 4
#define DHT2PIN 7

#define DHT1TYPE DHT11
#define DHT2TYPE DHT11

DHT dht1(DHT1PIN, DHT1TYPE); 
DHT dht2(DHT2PIN, DHT2TYPE);

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  Serial.println("Humidity sensors DHT11 tests!"); 

  dht1.begin(); 
  dht2.begin(); 
}

void loop() { 

  delay(2000);

  float h1 = dht1.readHumidity(); 
  float t1 = dht1.readTemperature(); 
  float h2 = dht2.readHumidity(); 
  float t2 = dht2.readTemperature();

  if (isnan(t1) || isnan(h1)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT #1");
  } else {  
    Serial.print(h1); Serial.print(" \t"); 
  } 

  if (isnan(t2) || isnan(h2)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT #2");
  } else { 
    Serial.print(h2); 
    Serial.print(" \t"); 
  } 
  Serial.println(); 
}
```

and my serial port out is;
[image]

and I want it to be like that;
[image]

Any help will appreciated.

Comment: Did you add a RTC to the circuit?

Comment: No I want it to read the clock from compter.

Comment: Then there's no way the Arduino can know the time. Write a custom host-side program.

Comment: Isn't there a way to know the time of data that printed on a serial?

Comment: Sure. The host will know. But that means a host-side program.

Comment: So no way to print it to serial window, thanks.

Comment: Like he said, there *is* a way to print it but it would require a program running on your PC; the Arduino is not omniscient, your PC keeps track of the current time whereas the Arduino only knows about time as it relates to executing instructions, therefore your PC has to either inform the Arduino of the time when the sketch first begins to run, and let the Arduino regularly update the time on its own or, even better, your PC program should listen to the serial port and print the current time in addition to whatever DHT sensor data it receives from the Arduino.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104834/how-to-log-serial-data-with-time-stamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using millis() function. And now I ca get results like these;
[image]

My code is;

```
#include <Sensirion.h>
#include "DHT.h"
unsigned long time;

#define DHT1PIN 4
#define DHT2PIN 7

#define DHT1TYPE DHT11
#define DHT2TYPE DHT11

DHT dht1(DHT1PIN, DHT1TYPE);
DHT dht2(DHT2PIN, DHT2TYPE);

const uint8_t dataPin =  9;              // SHT serial data
const uint8_t sclkPin =  8;              // SHT serial clock
const uint8_t ledPin  = 13;              // Arduino built-in LED
const uint32_t TRHSTEP   = 1000UL;       // Sensor query period
const uint32_t BLINKSTEP =  250UL;       // LED blink period

Sensirion sht = Sensirion(dataPin, sclkPin);

uint16_t rawData;
float temperature;
float humidity;
float dewpoint;

byte ledState = 0;
byte measActive = false;
byte measType = TEMP;

unsigned long trhMillis = 0;             // Time interval tracking
unsigned long blinkMillis = 0;

void setup() {
  dht1.begin();
  dht2.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("In.(%) In.Tem(*C) Out.(%) Time");
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  delay(15);                           // Wait >= 11 ms before first cmd
  // Demonstrate blocking calls
  sht.measTemp(&rawData);              // sht.meas(TEMP, &rawData, BLOCK)
  temperature = sht.calcTemp(rawData);
  sht.measHumi(&rawData);              // sht.meas(HUMI, &rawData, BLOCK)
  humidity = sht.calcHumi(rawData, temperature);
  dewpoint = sht.calcDewpoint(humidity, temperature);
  logData();
}

void loop() {



  unsigned long curMillis = millis();          // Get current time

  // Rapidly blink LED.  Blocking calls take too long to allow this.
  if (curMillis - blinkMillis >= BLINKSTEP) {  // Time to toggle the LED state?
    ledState ^= 1;
    digitalWrite(ledPin, ledState);
    blinkMillis = curMillis;
  }

  // Demonstrate non-blocking calls
  if (curMillis - trhMillis >= TRHSTEP) {      // Time for new measurements?
    measActive = true;
    measType = TEMP;
    sht.meas(TEMP, &rawData, NONBLOCK);      // Start temp measurement
    trhMillis = curMillis;
  }
  if (measActive && sht.measRdy()) {           // Note: no error checking
    if (measType == TEMP) {                  // Process temp or humi?
      measType = HUMI;
      temperature = sht.calcTemp(rawData); // Convert raw sensor data
      sht.meas(HUMI, &rawData, NONBLOCK);  // Start humidity measurement

      float h2 = dht2.readHumidity();
      float t2 = dht2.readTemperature();


      Serial.print(humidity);
      Serial.print(" \t");
      Serial.print(temperature);
      Serial.print(" \t");

      if (isnan(t2) || isnan(h2)) {
        Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT #1");
      } else {
        Serial.print(h2);
        Serial.print(" \t");

        //time = millis();
        //prints time since program started
        Serial.println(curMillis);
      }
      Serial.println();
    }
    else {
      measActive = false;
      humidity = sht.calcHumi(rawData, temperature); // Convert raw sensor data
      dewpoint = sht.calcDewpoint(humidity, temperature);
      logData();
    }
  }
}

void logData() {
}
```

But the difference is that I am using SHT75 instead of another DHT11 so I am simultaneously acquiring data from the both of them. Thanks for everyone!